# Concatenate Int to String in LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, t-sql

I have the following LINQ query.

```
var providers = from c in Repository.Query<Company>()
                where !c.IsDeleted
                select new { c.Description, Id = "C" + c.Id };
```

I'm trying to concatenate the ID to "C". So, for example, if `c.Id` is 35 then the result should be "C35".

This obviously doesn't work because you can't add an integer (`c.Id`) to a string. I could easily resolve this in C# using `string.Format()` or converting the type. But how can I do this in LINQ?

Comment: Your example query should work just fine.

Comment: I don't understand the question. The code you have written will work just fine.

Comment: Your issue may be Culture related. I can think of two ways of doing this. First method is call `ToList()` after where clause and then call `Select`. The second method is use [DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.asnonunicode(v=vs.113).aspx).

Comment: @RobertMcKee...No. He should get `System.NotSupportedException` by running this query and the error would be: *Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.*

Comment: @user2946329 I just ran a mockup of his code and it works perfectly.

Comment: @MattRowland...It runs perfectly. But check the `providers`'s  result.

Comment: @user2946329 It is an `IEnumerable` of anonymous types.

Comment: I understand that the goal is to check the Id of the anonymous types. Again, the code that you have posted will work. In the mock up that I did after @RobertMcKee was questioned I received the correct `Id` values.

Comment: @JonathanWood I'm honestly surprised someone with as much rep as you is posting this kind of question on stack overflow. Not only did you not test it, but your question isn't very clear. Why you would post this is beyond me. Not only do you *not* include the problem you're having, you're writing assumptions (such as `This obviously doesn't work because you can't add an integer (c.Id) to a string` - which is completely testable even in a console application) which invalidates the whole question as the assumption is wrong. This is quite simply "I'm too lazy/unable to test it - test it for me".

Comment: My comment had nothing to do with worthiness. I meant that you've been on SO long enough to know what is and is not a good/acceptable question here. Your question shows absolutely zero effort on your behalf, as evidenced by the fact that commenters were able to test it for you within minutes. There is nothing of value in this question for the community. It is, quite simply, a 'do my work for me' question with no effort on your behalf. I'd recommend reading up on the posting standards of SO

Comment: @Rob: I explained above that I had to complete some other work before my code would run and I could test it. So now I've done that other work and guess what: it *doesn't* work. So thanks for giving your attitude while adding absolutely nothing to the discussion. I hope you feel good about your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx):

```
var xd = (from c in Repository.Query<Company>()
           where !c.IsDeleted
           select new { c.Description, Id = "C" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)c.Id).Trim()});
```

Answer (score 2):

When you need functionality of .NET only in preparing the result (as opposed to, say, filtering, which should be done on RDBMS side to avoid bringing too much data in memory) the common trick is to complete the conversion in memory using the `AsEnumerable` method:

```
var providers = Repository.Query<Company>()
    .Where(c => !c.IsDeleted)
    .Select(c => new { c.Description, c.Id }) // <<== Prepare raw data
    .AsEnumerable() // <<== From this point it's LINQ to Object
    .Select(c => new { c.Description, Id = "C"+c.Id }); // <<== Construct end result
```

Comment: You're missing int to string conversion.

Comment: Yes, I thought of this. It's just that I know SQL can do this and was hoping there was a way to  specify that from LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have written will work fine. Here is a mock up of the same code and it outputs the `Id`'s

```
class Company
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}

static void Main()
{
    //setup
    var list = new List<Company>();
    list.Add(new Company
    {
        Description = "Test",
        Id = 35,
        IsDeleted = false
    });
    list.Add(new Company
    {
        Description = "Test",
        Id = 52,
        IsDeleted = false
    });
    list.Add(new Company
    {
        Description = "Test",
        Id = 75,
        IsDeleted = true
    });

    /* code you are looking for */
    var providers = from c in list
                    where !c.IsDeleted
                    select new { c.Description, Id = "C" + c.Id };

    foreach (var provider in providers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(provider.Id);
    }

        Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: It should. If not then use `Repository.Query<Company>().ToList()`. When in doubt `ToList()` it out.

Comment: In fact, this does *not* work in the LINQ to SQL statement. Yes, you can use `ToList()` (or `AsEnumerable()` as dasblinkenlight suggested). But I was trying to figure out how to perform this in the SQL select statement.

Answer (score 0):

What about string format

```
var providers = from c in Repository.Query<Company>()
                where !c.IsDeleted
                select new { c.Description, Id = "C" + c.Id.ToString() };
```

Comment: I addressed that in my question. SQL doesn't support that syntax.

Comment: then i will try "C" + c.Id.ToString()